# How to set phone speaker as default audio output in webview (Ionic)

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, webview, twilio

I have implemented twilio VOIP in ionic framework. When i trigger call at that time phone speaker will serve as default audio output source instead of phone default speaker.

I have  try using getUserMedia() but i haven't fount correct way.

I want something cool like audio.setSpeaker(phoneSpeaker)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found cordova plugin that toggle speakers.

these plugin will found here
https://github.com/alongubkin/audiotoggle

> cordova plugin add audiotoggle